# Is there any alternative for href in React to download a file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have a folder called "Uploads" it is a static file, I am trying to upload my Resume in that folder, but I am unable to download it using href tag it is unable to find that path, but if I try to display an Image using src with the same path it's working.

Basically:
- ---- This is working

<Button href=`/uploads\\image -1618416495674.png` download> Download CV   ---- This is not downloading

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a anchor tag to download , not button , you can use button inside anchor tag , do like below

```
<a href={"/uploads\\image -1618416495674.png"} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" download>
   <Button>
     Download CV
   </Button>
</a>
```